# More show views per resource through more controller actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

If I have a foo resource and I would like to display information about foo differently and RESTfully per user request, how do I break out FooController#show into more complex showing behavior? Is the best way to do this to write controller actions?

For example, I want to send a request that responds with a page that only shows foo.name, or foo.email with another request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just send in a parameter (params[:facet] or something) that determines the aspect of your Foo resource that you want to show.

Then you could branch on the value of this parameter in your views, displaying only what you want to show for each facet of Foo.

Comment: or better yet, you could branch in your controller and choose to render different templates

Comment: Thank you, this helped me. I was having a hard time reading the api for something like form_for. But now it looks simpler than I thought: You can send an arbitrary parameter to an action, if you've defined that action in routes, with: form_for "some_param_name", someaction_foo_path(@foo)